# Any suggestions of a Single Sign-On to users from external apps (Mobile) to Magneto 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, api

The titles say it all.  Is there any extension, or suggestions to add this feature to Magento 2 store?  I want users to access the store from a 3rd-party mobile app.
And from there, users will be able to access the store without login again.

Thank you.

Comment: you will have to write custom rest api's to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Token based authentication: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

For example: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-quote.html

Magento swagger: https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have gone through almost all the resources I could find regarding this. We have a mobile app that we want users to log in to with their info, or use the Magento 2 conditions to login from that app. Are there any extensions to achieve this?